# Retrieve the specific node in wso2esb using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and following is my message :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<user>sps</user>
<pwd>sps123</pwd>
</request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to retrieve **user** information for that i have done like this

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/request/user
```

But I'm not getting anything.If i tried with

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body
```

Then i'm getting

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Body>
<request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<user>sps</user>
<pwd>sps123</pwd>
</request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</soapenv:Body>
```

How should i get user information?

Answer (score 0):

with

```
data(//*:Envelope/*:Body/*:request/*:user)
```

output is

```
sps
```

with

```
/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:request/*:user
```

output is

```
<user xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">sps</user>
```

Comment: this is adapted from Jens Erat's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087827/sql-server-xquery-with-default-namespace